# Meaning of the word Oleracea

Tags: taxonomy, nomenclature, etymology

What does "oleracea", as appears in numerous plant species (scientific) names, mean? Examples: *Euterpa oleracea, Brassica oleracea, Portulaca oleracea, Acmella oleracea, Spilanthes oleracea*.

Answer (score 4):

It means ["vegetable"](http://www.wordsense.eu/holeraceus/).
I think it's because people use those plants for food